# Serenity BDD reports filenames

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd

I am using the Serenity BDD tool Version 1.2.1-rc.3 with JUnit 4 to automate some regression testing. The project is working fine so far but I want to be able to rename the generated reports. At the moment they are called something like this:

*62e91fe28f676d9f760e63756d4ba1d2.html*

I want them to be named after the testcase creating them. I have not seen anything about this in the Serenity Reference Manual nor elsewhere I could think of. I even added `serenity.compress.filenames=false` to `serenity.properties` and it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `serenity.compress.filenames=false` should work. However I would advise against doing this, except in debugging mode, if you are running any builds on Windows. The generated filenames will quickly exceed the maximum allowed Windows path length of 240 chars.

Comment: Thanks a lot perhaps the problem is the path lenght I will investigate on it.